# in sqlalchemy can or_ look into two columns when more than one word is entered?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following command that's kind of working as expected:

```
DBSession.query(Users).filter(or_(Users.first_name.contains(search_term),Users.last_name.contains(search_term))).all()
```

I searches both first and last name in my Users table, so I can find `bob smith` by searching either `bob` or `smith`, but I get no results when I search `bob smith`.  This is obviously because bob is in the first_name column and not `bob smith` so it fails.  But is there a way to do this kind of search within sqlalchemy?

I know worst I can create a column with the full name but I thought I'd ask just in case it was possible. I'm also tagging this as sql just in case its possible with raw sql then I will just try to igure out the sqlalchemy version based on the raw query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use [Hybrid Attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) extension:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class User(Base):
    #...
    first_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    @hybrid_property
    def _full_name_last_first(self):
        """ @note: used only for search [last, first].  """
        return self.last_name + ", " + self.first_name

def test_search(search_term):
    q = session.query(User)
    q = q.filter(
            or_(
                User.first_name.contains(search_term),
                User.last_name.contains(search_term),
                User.full_name.contains(search_term),
                User._full_name_last_first.contains(search_term),
                ),
            )
    q = q.order_by(User.id)
    return q.all()

r1 = test_search('John Williams')
assert len(r1) == 1

r1 = test_search('Williams, Jo')
assert len(r1) == 1
```